ellipsis of 'being' in "He sleeps with the window being open."

He sleeps with the window being open.


He sleeps with the window open.


He has been sleeping with the window having been open ever since someone broke the window in his room.

We usually see and say the second sentence: He sleeps with the window open.
Is there any reason that the first sentence is hard to see?
Is the third sentence awkward, ungrammatical, or sementically senseless?

If by 'hard to see' you mean 'seldom seen', that's because it's incorrect English. The idiomatic usage is with the window open. Your third example is even more strange; you don't need a past tense to describe the state of the window as well as his sleeping.
We do use being in some contexts;

The window being open, the room was rather cold. (=because the window was open).


And another thing we don’t say is, *”The room was cold because the window was being open.”

@Kate Bunting What about this: With the winodw being open, the room was rather cold.

@gomadeng It's grammatical, but not idiomatic. "With the window open, the room was cold." But even more common is "Because thw window was open, the room was cold." "With" is usually used when you're contrasting things: "With the window open, the room is cold; otherwise, it's warm."
